# Slicing a Mysql array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query

```
$raw_resultsplaylists = mysql_query("SELECT songs.*, playlists.title as `playlist_title`
                                 FROM song_main AS songs
                                 JOIN songs_in_list AS playlist_songs 
                                  ON songs.ID = playlist_songs.song_id
                                 JOIN playlists 
                                 ON playlist_songs.playlist_id = playlists.ID
                                WHERE playlists.owner_id = '$userid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

that retrieves an array of information like that:

```
  playlist_title      song_name              song_url        song_artist
     -------------------------------------------------------------------        
     foo1               woops                 www.                -
     foo1               blah                  www.                -
     foo2               blop                  www.                -
     foo1               woop                  www.                -
     foo3               bob                   www.                -      
     foo1               dylan                 www.                -
```

My question is how can I slice the Mysql array to get all the rows with the same `playlist_title` in a separate array so I can display them in separate html tables for instance :

html table 1:

```
 playlist_title      song_name              song_url        song_artist
    -------------------------------------------------------------------        
     foo1               woops                 www.                -
     foo1               blah                  www.                -
     foo1               woop                  www.                -    
     foo1               dylan                 www.                -
```

html table 2

```
    playlist_title      song_name           song_url        song_artist
     -------------------------------------------------------------------        
     foo2               blop                  www.                -
     foo2               dylan                 www.                -
```

etc...

Comment: where is your query ?

Comment: Will that give me different arrays that I could display in different html tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to draw the idea..

```
do{

  $groupedItems[$row['pname']][] = $row; //every row with the same pname will be "grouped" in the same array level

}while..
```

And then...

```
foreach($groupedItems as $group){
  //bla bla
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it seems to be exactly what I need, could you just explain to me what the foreach does ?

Comment: It does exactly what the name suggest.. For each element in the array do something. More info, as usual, in the manual: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: So I can use the foreach to display the elements in different html tables right ? Thanks again

Comment: Is your data, do whatever you want :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no "arrays" in SQL. It's all rows and columns. What you want is, maybe:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE pname='foo1'
```

Or perhaps:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY pname
```

Where you can do the splitting in your application.

Answer (score 0):

For html table 1:

```
mysql_query("SELECT songs.*, playlists.title as `playlist_title`
                             FROM song_main AS songs
                             JOIN songs_in_list AS playlist_songs 
                             ON songs.ID = playlist_songs.song_id
                             JOIN playlists 
                             ON playlist_songs.playlist_id = playlists.ID
                             WHERE playlists.owner_id = '$userid'
                             AND playlist_title='foo1'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I don't know the playlist_title when I am sending the query to Mysql.