# Combine 2 queries mysql and organise results 5:1 insertion

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, ads

I'm overwhelmed with a prob silly question.

I'm working with php + mysql the ads on my site.

I was thinking in using the same table for ads than I use for normal posts so, having 7 different types of ads, combine 1 "sponsored" ad type every 5 normal.

```
 CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `type` enum('type1','type2','type3','type4','type5','type6','type7','sponsored') CHARACTER SET utf16 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'type1',
 
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16 COLLATE=utf16_unicode_ci
```

Desiderable result should should be:

ads type1-type7: 1,2,3,4,5
ad sponsored (1)
ads type1-type7: 6,7,8,9,10
ad sponsored (2)
ads type1-type7: 11,12,13,14,15
and continue repeating pattern for results, if there's no more sponsors then insert a default ad.

If no sponsored ad relate found with the query parameters:

1,2,3,4,5-(default)-6,7,8,9,10-(default)-11,12,13,14,15-(default)...

Right now I'm using a php file inserting a default sponsored ad every 5 ads "normal".

SAMPLE DATA

```
post_id  type    location
1        type2    Bahamas
2        type4    Seville
4       sponsored   Bahamas
5       sponsored   Singapur
6       type1     Bilbao
7      sponsored   Bahamas
8     type1       Bahamas
9     type6       Bahamas
10     type4       Bahamas
11     type1       New York
12     type1       Bahamas
13     type6       Bahamas
```

OUTPUT TO DISPLAY AT INDEX
SAMPLE DATA

```
post_id  type    location
1        type2    Bahamas
2        type4    Seville
6       type1     Bilbao
8      type1       Bahamas
9      type6       Bahamas
xx     sponsored   xxxx    >> RANDOM SPONSOR
10     type4       Bahamas
11     type1       New York
12     type1       Bahamas
13     type6       Bahamas
```

SAMPLE NEEDED OUTPUT when defined location "Bahamas"

```
post_id  type    location
1    type2       Bahamas
8     type1       Bahamas
9     type6       Bahamas
10     type4       Bahamas
12     type1       Bahamas
2     sponsored Bahamas
13     type6       Bahamas
```

Right now I'm doing 2 basic SELECT queries (1 for normal ads, 1 for sponsored ads) and storing results on arrays that I combine.

With php I'm inserting 1 ad every 5 normal ads.

My aim is optimize the way I'm doing it, as I don't know if there is any mysql argument that can improve my formula.

YES, ADyson sounds like an insert because the user insert the sponsored ads like a normal ad that's why I was trying to organise everything with the same table. Otherwise I can create another table for ads but don't see the difference as long as I don't know much mysql. I'm lost with JOIN, INNER JOIN, INTERSECT, IF... I'm looking through different posts here but can't see anything matching this question.

Maybe I'm after something like [Slicing a Mysql array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993319/slicing-a-mysql-array), not sure.

Thanks in advance-

Comment: The question is not clear. Provide: precise MySQL version info, CREATE TABLE for source table, some sample data as INSERT INTO, desired output for this data with detailed explanations for each output row.

Comment: Read slow please-

I have a table `posts` wich store all the ads (7 different types of ads + 1 type called SPONSORED).

I need to insert 1 sponsored ad every 5 of the other type ads.

Thanks

Comment: You want us to work with your problem but do not work with it self? it's your choice...

Comment: I don't really understand the problem either. Something to do with how to insert the sponsored adverts? It's unclear what exactly is giving you difficulty in that task. Please edit the question

Comment: thanks guys, check if I explained myself better now

Comment: Thanks but still there isn't actually a question or a clear problem. You've listed some requirements in terms of wanting to insert posts in a certain pattern, but you've shown no code (although mentioned there is a PHP file, you didn't show any code from it) or told us what's going wrong when you try to do it. It's also unclear how the code is supposed to determine whether there are any more sponsored ads left or not - where does that info come from? Also how does it know what type the others should be?

Comment: Or are you just asking us if this is a good design? Again, there's no actual question or problem statement in your post.

Comment: I think is super clear, I have 2 queries:

Comment: Edit the question to add more info, don't jumble it into the comments. If you've got two queries already, show them in your question. We can't tell you how to merge your queries, or anything else, if you don't show them. Also show any attempts you've made to merge them so far.

Comment: I think is super clear, I have 2 queries: 1 is the SELECT * WHERE type != sponsored and 2 is the SELECT * WHERE type == sponsored. I wnat to know if there is a better way to insert 1 result from the query 2 every 5 results from the query 1 than an array in php. The main reason is optimize the resources that's why I'm asking. To check if there are sponsored left or not I will pass other variables, like location, but it doesn't matter as long as I can implement a way to set a default sponsored ad to insert. For example INSERT ad-sponsor id 1 IF row results for ad-sponsor location Bahamas was 0.

Comment: why not just `SELECT *` without a WHERE? Then they'll all be selected. Of course you might need something to order them by. We can't see how they're currently ordered in the table, if at all. Some sample source data would be great. That would contribute, along with code, to providing us with a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: BTW the question sounded like it was about inserting data _into_ the posts table, not selecting it for output (presumably to insert into an array?). _That's_ why you should show your full code (**in the question, please, not in comments**) and explain precisely what is going on. _That's_ why people are finding things unclear. We can't see your machine and we're not mind-readers, we can only use what's in front of us, which wasn't very much. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Every 5 posts I will insert 1 ad.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($posts as $post) { 
if(++$counter % 5 === 1) { 
 include './advertisment/advertisment.php';
    }
```

Now on top of my query for advertisment:

```
  $limit = intval($counter);
  $offset = intval($counter/5);
```

In my case the query for ads looks for advertisment by location if the parameter location is passed, if there is no location passed retrieve any ad and for the rest of inserts use a default ad. My sponsors ad are valid for 3 months, that's why I also check the interval.

```
if ((isset($_GET['location'])) && (!empty($_GET['location']))) {                
                $location = $_GET['location'];
                $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts`
            WHERE type = 'advertisment' AND DATE(post_on) > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 WEEK 
            AND id IN (SELECT id FROM `postcontenttable` WHERE location = :location AND posts.id = postcontenttable.post_id)   
            ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
                $query->bindParam(":location" , $location , PDO::PARAM_STR);                                
            } else {    
                $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts`
            WHERE type = 'advertisment' AND DATE(post_on) > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 WEEK   
            ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");              
            }
            $query->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->execute();
            $ads = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if (!($query->rowCount() == 0)) { 

foreach($ads as $post) { 
if(++$offset % 1 === 0) { 
    break;
} 
}
} else { ?>
<?php include './advertisment/ad.php'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

So I'm inserting 1 ad every 5 normal posts, exposing sponsors on location of their preference and when not available any sponsor inserting a default ad (you can use that to retrieve for a random sponsor).